# Cannot access my workgroup from dolphin in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, kubuntu, file-sharing

I upgraded my installation of Kubuntu 19.10 to 20.04 some days ago and I discovered that now I can't access to my workgroup from dolphin in the LAN. Dolphin show a text in red and said that it cannot find any workgroup in my LAN, and also says that this can be cause some firewall. However I checked the firewall of kubuntu and it is still disabled.

But, strangely, the links that I created previously to places on the LAN works nicely. I dont know what to do, I tried to put the client min protocol in smb.conf to CORE as I had read in other similar questions but this doesn't work. I have set client max and client min protocol to NT1 as it was working before I upgraded to 20.04, but it doesn't work (by doesn't work I mean that I cannot access the workgroup from dolphin, the shared folders can be accessed from direct links).

Moreover: I have a fresh install of kubuntu 20.04 in a laptop and it have the same problem.

There is a way to fix this behavior?